# Reading zip file off the internet: Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r

I have a url I'm trying to directly read into R using the following code:

```
url <- "https://oehha.ca.gov/media/downloads/calenviroscreen/document/ces3results.xlsx"
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(url, temp)
data <- read.table(unz(temp, 'ces3results.xlsx'))
unlink(temp)
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") :
  cannot open zip file '/var/folders/94/1ldxgg4d3tzg4sqznhj8m2qr0000gn/T//RtmpcHqBEX/fileb6f920054f3a'
```

From what I've researched, this may be a matter of the website not allowing people to download data directly from their url. Is it that or is my code just faulty?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL does not seem to point to a .zip archive, and you can actually open it directly using `openxlsx::read.xlsx`.

```
url <- "https://oehha.ca.gov/media/downloads/calenviroscreen/document/ces3results.xlsx"
data1 <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(url)
```

To first download, then open it you may adapt your method a little. Use `mode="wz"`, leave out the `unz`, finally method as above.

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(url, destfile = temp, mode="wb")
data2 <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(temp)
unlink(temp)  ## cleanup

stopifnot(all.equal(data1, data2))
```